# In Linux, How to get the backtrace of a program running under valgrind

Tags: c++, linux, valgrind

OS : Linux RedHat 7.7

Program is running under valgrind

I want to get the current backtrace in order to find out what the program is doing (similar to use of gstack when NOT running under valgrind).

Use of 'gstack' does not show useful information when the program is under valgrind.

Is there anyway this can be achieved ? vgdb or any other tool ?

Comment: So you know about `vgdb`. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer, 'vgdb   v.info scheduler"